# Windows media player 12 not launching from custom program

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

There is a program we use for testing that calls windows media player and plays a media file.  The problem is that windows media player fails to load unless you open and close it before starting the program. After that the program will open it every time without a hitch but after a reboot it is lost and you must do it again. My question is what could be voilate setting could windows media player have that would be lost on a reboot?

I have tried programs like Regshot to capture changes to the registry that might be delated on reboot. The code for the program is very straight forward simply calling windows media player with a parameter with the media to play. Using process montior I have determined that is is crashing shortly after the program executes it.

I am at a lost on this problem as I can not find what if anything it is changing to run windows media player.

Comment: How are you starting the program?  Are you passing to shell.execute?

Comment: I didn't write the code but it looks like they calling a command prompt and having it launch from their rather than forwarding it to shell execute. The tricky part is it isn't launching wmplayer its launching a skin file *.wms that is associated with wmplayer. I was told it was doing it this way because it uses less memory.